# To find execution time of loading mysql database into kafka topic by avro

Tags: apache-kafka

How to find the time taken to load mysql database into kafka topic while using avro serialization format ?

I have used this command--
    `curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" \
    -H  "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/ \
    -d '{
    "name":"mysql-localhost-avro2-connector-1",
    "config":{
    "connector.class":"io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "database.user":"debezium",
    "database.server.id":"42",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers":"localhost:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic":"localhost-avro2-connector.history",
    "database.server.name":"localhost-avro2-connector",
    "heartbeat.interval.ms":"10000",
    "snapshot.delay.ms":"30000",
    "database.port":"3306",
    "include.schema.changes":"true",
    "table.whitelist" :     "kafka_test.Product,kafka_test.sales,kafka_test.Persons",
    "database.hostname":"localhost",
    "database.password":"dbz",
    "poll.interval.ms":"30000"
    }
}'`

[topics and streams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPdGg.png)

Comment: How are you doing the load? You need to be more specific in your question.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I have added some more information, please have a look and guide.